# Can I declare advice for surrounding an advice itself in aop java?

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I have made an annotation(@MethodLogger) and written an aspect over it which basically logs the timing of the method and keep storing it. So on any method on which i put that annotation it works fine
But in a special use case I need to monitor an advice itself:

eg:

```
@MethodLogger
@Around("some function specified")
public Object method(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable{


// code here

}
```

But this thing does not works. It never invokes my annotations aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work in Spring AOP, as is [documented here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-at-aspectj):

> **Advising aspects with other aspects?**
>
> In Spring AOP, it is not possible to have aspects themselves be the target of advice from other aspects. The `@Aspect` annotation on a class marks it as an aspect, and hence excludes it from auto-proxying.

If you want to do this, you need to activate full [AspectJ via LTW](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) in Spring. Then you can target advices directly if you know their method name. There even is a special pointcut designator `adviceexecution()` if you generally want to limit pointcut matching to advice execution or exclude the latter from matching via `!adviceexecution()`. For more details please check the AspectJ documentation.